# CountIf Statement

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I'm trying to count the number of instances where a date is entered in a column in Excel. I can't seem to construct the right CountIf statement.  I'm trying to count the number of times an instance a date is greater than or equal to 1/5/2015.

```
=COUNTIF(L:L, >="01/05/15")
```

Comment: can you show us your trials? what have you done so far?

Comment: Code! I must see the code!

Comment: Sorry!!! I'm a first time poster.

Comment: Here's the code: =COUNTIF(L:L, >="01/05/15")

Comment: @MarkDouglas since you are new:  you should use the edit button to include additional information in the question itself, rather than add it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here

1. Enclose the comparison operator in quotes
2. Specify the date to compare to as a *date* not a string

Better yet put the comparison date in a cell (let's say `A1`).  Formula becomes

```
 =COUNTIF(L:L, ">=" & A1)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! Now that I have the foundation, I can expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula:

`=COUNTIF(L:L, ">=01/05/15")`